# How to configure Google Cloud Storage in Craft v3?

Tags: craft3, upgrades, storage

I'm doing the Craft 3 upgrade and I can't figure out how to connect our Google Cloud Storage. Back with Craft 2 I used a `Google Access Key` and `Access Secret Key`. Now I am asked for a `Project ID` and the `Contents of the access key file`.

After reviewing the plugin's README I read about getting the *Service Account Credentials JSON*. Which after a search, I found were generated through (Google's Identify Platform, IAM)[https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount] which allowed me to create a Service Account for the project and I downloaded a JSON file.

I went to enter my **Project ID** and the **contents of the JSON**, thinking this would solve it, but I keep getting a permissions error. Despite going through the project permissions and the created account permissions. I've tried with Legacy owner permissions and still nothing.

```
[IAM USER] does not have storage.bucket.list permission to access project [PROJECT # ID]
```

Am I missing anything or are these not the right credentials?

Comment: The documentation on what the google-cloud plugin wants for access key is laughably non-existant. I'm not sure how they expect people to use this plugin without any docs or at LEAST a sentence or two describing what information they're looking for.

Comment: OP & @Tyguy7 anybody figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post has a pretty good walkthrough applicable to the version valid then:

[How to set up Craft to use Google Cloud Storage?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/how-to-set-up-craft-to-use-google-cloud-storage)